# Ubuntu Desktop Image( iso)

Tags: system-installation

I've seen some popular E-Commerce sites selling Ubuntu Desktop DVD's of both the 64Bit and 32Bit Architecture.I want to install a 32Bit version on a system as It is old and can support only 32 bit version  has only 2GB RAM and AMD Athlon X2 270 processor.Do I need to download It and check [How To MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) before burning a  CD for installation?

Comment: Just download, burn to DVD, and install.  No need to buy.

Comment: Alternatively, you could write the image on an USB stick (using [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net)), but if the computer is very old it might not be capable of booting from USB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a DVD or USB yourself in Windows

If you're using Windows,You can follow these steps.

- [Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
- [How to burn a DVD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

A dual core computer isn't really "old", possibly a little slow for Unity, but definitely not too old for a DE like [XFCE](http://xubuntu.org/), LXDE ([Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [Ubuntu help on Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu)), etc... just get the 32-bit version (if your CPU really can't run 64-bit, but the 32-bit is usually lighter on ram anyway).

Try running the live versions of a few distros (could browse http://www.distrowatch.com for "old computer" or "beginner" ones) and pick one you like. But don't get fooled by the slow DVD or  USB read times.